# Setting environment variables with Jupyter for doing `from module import function`

Tags: python, environment-variables, jupyter

I have a python script called score.py that contains the following code:

```
def init():
   print(os.getenv('hello')
```

I would like to test a method from this script with the following code in Jupyter, where the working directory contains score.py:

```
import os

os.environ['hello']='somevar'
from score import init
init()
```

Unfortunately, this code fails because 'hello' is not one of the variables that score.py can see. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that this is some `kernel` related error. Have you also tried restructuring your code to the following and see if that works?

```
from score import init
import os
os.environ['hello']='somevar'
init()
```

If that doesnt work try the alternative way by setting an env variable in a jupyter notebook, just use a `%` magic commands, either `%env` or `%set_env`, e.g., `%env MY_VAR=MY_VALUE` or `%env MY_VAR MY_VALUE`. See [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

In the worse case, just save it in a `.env` file and then load them in your script. This will most likely work.